# Selecting from a Complex View takes a long time in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to select data from a complex View, but the query materialization takes a long time (4 seconds).

This is the Code:

```
            // 1. Perform a Search by name on tbl_member
            var memberIDs = (from m in DC.tbl_Member
                             where (m.FirstNameFiltered + ' ' + m.LastNameFiltered).Contains(fileteredName)
                             select m.MemberID).Take(10).ToList();

            // 2. Get the members data from View_QuickSearch
            var members = (from m in DC.View_QuickSearch
                           where memberIDs.Contains(m.MemberID)
                           select m);

            // 3. Materialize the results
            members.ToList();
```

The first statement makes the actual search in tbl_Member and returns the needed IDs. Its time is expected and it runs smoothly in 2 seconds.

The second statement retrieves data from the Complex View according to the 10 IDs returned.
When I call **members.ToList()**, it takes a long time (4 seconds).

I got the **members** query from the Visual Studio debugger and put it in SSMS, it returns the data instantaneously in a few milliseconds.

```
SELECT [t0].[MemberID], [t0].[fullName], [t0].[fullNameFiltered], [t0].[Mobile], [t0].[NationalID], [t0].[Job], [t0].[Company], [t0].[EDUClass], [t0].[AttendanceChurch], [t0].[FamilyChurch]
FROM [dbo].[View_QuickSearch] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[MemberID] IN (756, 969, 1349, 1390, 1486, 1900, 2234, 2697, 2852, 3286)
```

So this means the problem is Not in the View itself, or in the select statement, or the indices.

Comment: You need to look at the actual execution plan of the query submitted through code and compare it to the one executed from SSMS; you will likely have two or more different execution plans in cache.

Comment: Is lazy loading enabled? also check for any network latency

Comment: what are you using for filter name? ... where (m.FirstNameFiltered + ' ' + m.LastNameFiltered).Contains(fileteredName)

Comment: @VivekNuna The View_QuickSearch does not have any relations defined in LINQ.
I am running both set of queries (linq and sql) from the same machine (my machine), to a remote DB server, repeated many times.

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter filteredName is a string (ex: "John Risk")

Comment: It looks it is my mistake :( when I changed the IDs in the second query to larger numbers, it took a long time in SQL, to be similar to Linq. So I will need to work on optimizing the Query on SQL. Linq is innocent from slowness in this case :)

Comment: `where (m.FirstNameFiltered + ' ' + m.LastNameFiltered).Contains(fileteredName)` looks slow, maybe do something like `where DbFunctions.Like(m.FirstNameFiltered, firstName + "%") && DbFunctions.Like(m.LastNameFiltered, lastName + "%"))`

Comment: I removed the [linq-to-sql] tag, because LINQ-to-SQL (which is an old ORM) isn't used here.

Answer (score 0):

### To speed up the provided code, you can make a few optimizations:

1. Reduce database round-trips: Instead of executing separate queries to fetch member IDs and member data, you can combine the logic into a single query using joins.
2. Limit the query size early: Rather than fetching all matching members and then materializing the results, you can limit the number of results directly in the query.

### Here's an optimized version of the code:

```
var members = (from m in DC.View_QuickSearch
                       join member in DC.tbl_Member
                       on m.MemberID equals member.MemberID
                       where (member.FirstNameFiltered + " " + member.LastNameFiltered).Contains(filteredName)
                       select m).Take(10).ToList();
```

In this optimized code:

1. The tbl_Member table is joined with the View_QuickSearch view based
   on the MemberID column. This eliminates the need for a separate
   query to fetch member IDs.
2. The search condition is applied directly in the where clause of the
   query, combining the name filtering with the join condition.
3. The Take(10) method limits the query results to a maximum of 10
   records, reducing unnecessary data retrieval.
4. The ToList() method immediately materializes the results,
   eliminating the need for an additional query.

---

By combining the queries and applying the filtering and limiting earlier in the process, this optimized version should help improve the speed and efficiency of the code.

Comment: The query after the join is still slower than performing 2 separate queries, this happens when using linq, or when calling SQL directly.

This could be optimized by optimizing the indices on the server and sql query directives. However, let us first understand why reading from the view in the second query is slower in linq than in normal sql and try to solve this simpler query.

Comment: Did you run the optimized query? It is using a join which will be much quicker. I ran benchmark tests using your code vs optimized code and two tables with similar fields and the optimized code is twice as fast as the code you posted running two queries and then calling tolist.

Comment: Because you don't have the Complex View and its data. 
I ran the generated query from LINQ, directly on SQL, and it gave 5s.

From SQL, when separated, the first query takes 2 seconds, and the second one takes 0s.

Comment: you can't compare directly running on SQL vs LINQ non cached objects.

Comment: It looks it is my mistake :( when I changed the IDs in the second query to larger numbers, it took a long time in SQL, to be similar to Linq. So I will need to work on optimizing the Query on SQL. Linq is innocent from slowness in this case :)

I will use your combined query if other problems are resolved.

Comment: @JohnRisk Glad you were able to make some progress. Hope you find opt solution.